# WiX v3.7 - vbScript Custom Action BrowseForFolder() not returning individual file names

Tags: vbscript, wix, windows-installer, custom-action, wix3.7

I found a VB Script example for opening a file browser, which I used in a custom action in WiX. However, the VB Script function I use is called `BrowseForFolder()` (not browseforfile) and only seems to return a value when a directory is selected, but not when an individual file is selected. Here is the custom action:

```
<CustomAction Id="File" Script="vbscript" Execute="immediate" Return="ignore">
  <![CDATA[
    Dim shell
    Set shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application") 
    Dim file
    Set file = shell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose a file:", &H4000)
    Session.Property("FileName") = file.self.Path
  ]]>
</CustomAction>
```

Using this method, I can actually see individual files in the dialog, which is a step up from Wix's built-in directory browser.

Now I just need to be able to retrieve individual file names, not just names of folders.

Comment: Did you try testing outside a custom action?  I'd imagine you get the same results.  Seems to me that BrowseForFolder would only be returning folder objects based on the docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774065(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Do you know of any relatively short ways for displaying a file browser in vbscript if BrowseForFolder doesn't work?

Comment: Nope.  I see lots of articles with folks using hacks and undocumented APIs.  EG: https://gist.github.com/1932941‎ But nothing that looks sound.  I'd honestly recommend using a native custom action for this if you need it,  see IFileOpenDialog http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776913(v=vs.85).aspx#usage.  VBScript custom actions should really be avoided when possible: a number of enterprises disable VBScript entirely which would break installers that rely on it.  As another alternative, you could MSI UI with something like Wix's burn and define your own UI.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this code.

https://gist.github.com/wangye/1932941

and made some changes on it to a better understanding

```
WScript.Echo GetOpenFileName("C:\", "")

' 
' Description: VBScript/VBS open file dialog
'              Compatible with most Windows platforms
' Author: wangye  <pcn88 at hotmail dot com>
' Website: http://wangye.org
'
' dir is the initial directory; if no directory is
' specified "Desktop" is used.
' filter is the file type filter; format "File type description|*.ext"
' 
'

Public Function GetOpenFileName(dir, filter)
    Const msoFileDialogFilePicker = 3


If VarType(dir) <> vbString Or dir="" Then
    dir = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" ).SpecialFolders( "Desktop" )
End If

If VarType(filter) <> vbString Or filter="" Then
    filter = "All files|*.*"
End If

' try to choose the way to open the dialog box. Array: TryObjectNames
Dim i,j, objDialog, TryObjectNames
TryObjectNames = Array( _
    "UserAccounts.CommonDialog", _
    "MSComDlg.CommonDialog", _
    "MSComDlg.CommonDialog.1", _
    "Word.Application", _
    "SAFRCFileDlg.FileOpen", _
    "InternetExplorer.Application" _
    )

On Error Resume Next
Err.Clear

For i=0 To UBound(TryObjectNames)
    Set objDialog = WSH.CreateObject(TryObjectNames(i))
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
    Else
        Exit For
    End If
Next

' Select the way to dealing the object dialog
Select Case i
Case 0,1,2
    ' 0. UserAccounts.CommonDialog XP Only.
    ' 1.2. MSComDlg.CommonDialog MSCOMDLG32.OCX must registered.
    If i=0 Then
        objDialog.InitialDir = dir
    Else
        objDialog.InitDir = dir
    End If
    objDialog.Filter = filter
    If objDialog.ShowOpen Then
        GetOpenFileName = objDialog.FileName
    End If
Case 3
    ' 3. Word.Application Microsoft Office must installed.
    objDialog.Visible = False
    Dim objOpenDialog, filtersInArray
    filtersInArray = Split(filter, "|")
    Set objOpenDialog = _
        objDialog.Application.FileDialog( _
            msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        With objOpenDialog
        .Title = "Open File(s):"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = dir
        .Filters.Clear
        For j=0 To UBound(filtersInArray) Step 2
            .Filters.Add filtersInArray(j), _
                 filtersInArray(j+1), 1
        Next
        If .Show And .SelectedItems.Count>0 Then
            GetOpenFileName = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
        End With
        objDialog.Visible = True
        objDialog.Quit
    Set objOpenDialog = Nothing
Case 4
    ' 4. SAFRCFileDlg.FileOpen xp 2003 only
    ' See http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_ui_fileopen.php
    If objDialog.OpenFileOpenDlg Then
       GetOpenFileName = objDialog.FileName
    End If
Case 5
    Dim IEVersion,IEMajorVersion, hasCompleted
    hasCompleted = False
    Dim shell
    Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    ' ????IE??
    IEVersion = shell.RegRead( _
        "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Version")
    If InStr(IEVersion,".") > 0 Then
        ' ??????
        IEMajorVersion = CInt(Left(IEVersion, InStr(IEVersion,".")-1))
        If IEMajorVersion > 7 Then
            ' ???????7,?????IE7,???MSHTA??
            ' Bypasses c:\fakepath\file.txt problem
            ' http://pastebin.com/txVgnLBV
            Dim fso
            Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

            Dim tempFolder : Set tempFolder = fso.GetSpecialFolder(2)
            Dim tempName : tempName = fso.GetTempName()
            Dim tempFile : Set tempFile = tempFolder.CreateTextFile(tempName & ".hta")
            Dim tempBaseName
            tempBaseName = tempFolder & "\" & tempName
            tempFile.Write _
                "<html>" & _
                "  <head>" & _
                "    <title>Browse</title>" & _
                "  </head>" & _
                "  <body>" & _
                "    <input type='file' id='f'>" & _
                "    <script type='text/javascript'>" & _
                "      var f = document.getElementById('f');" & _
                "      f.click();" & _
                "      var fso = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');" & _
                "      var file = fso.OpenTextFile('" & _
                          Replace(tempBaseName,"\", "\\") & ".txt" & "', 2, true);" & _
                "      file.Write(f.value);" & _
                "      file.Close();" & _
                "      window.close();" & _
                "    </script>" & _
                "  </body>" & _
                "</html>"
            tempFile.Close
            Set tempFile = Nothing
            Set tempFolder = Nothing
            shell.Run tempBaseName & ".hta", 1, True
            Set tempFile = fso.OpenTextFile(tempBaseName & ".txt", 1)
            GetOpenFileName = tempFile.ReadLine
            tempFile.Close
            fso.DeleteFile tempBaseName & ".hta"
            fso.DeleteFile tempBaseName & ".txt"
            Set tempFile = Nothing
            Set fso = Nothing
            hasCompleted = True ' ??????
        End If
    End If
    If Not hasCompleted Then
        ' 5. InternetExplorer.Application IE must installed
        objDialog.Navigate "about:blank"
        Dim objBody, objFileDialog
        Set objBody = _
            objDialog.document.getElementsByTagName("body")(0)
        objBody.innerHTML = "<input type='file' id='fileDialog'>"
        while objDialog.Busy Or objDialog.ReadyState <> 4
            WScript.sleep 10
        Wend
        Set objFileDialog = objDialog.document.all.fileDialog
            objFileDialog.click
            GetOpenFileName = objFileDialog.value
    End If
    objDialog.Quit
    Set objFileDialog = Nothing
    Set objBody = Nothing
    Set shell = Nothing
Case Else
     MsgBox("No file dialog component found", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
End Select

Set objDialog = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: please do not just include a link, try to answer the question.